# Regex greater than $75

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex that approves values of $75 or greater and rejects anything lower than $75.  Here is what I have at this point, which only approves $75, but nothing above.  [7-9][5-9]|([1-9][0-9]+)

Comment: You really don't need a regex here.

Comment: Why not just parse it into a number?

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing this with a regex instead of just stripping out the $ sign and comparing it in code?

Comment: Regular expressions standing in for relational operators on numeric quantities never work well. Don't do it that way. Use a parser on a currency type instead.

Comment: @RealSkeptic In addition to the fact that it does not support anything about 100 anyway :-)

Comment: I need regex to put into the database to compare transactions that are being sent mobile alerts.  It's a very archaic system......but it's what I was given when I started here.....

Answer (score 7):

While the best answer is likely "don't use regular expressions", it's possible that this might need to be done as part of a larger regular expression, where the larger use makes sense. In that case (and *only* that case):

```
7[5-9]|[8-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?
```

i.e one of:

- 75-79
- 80-99
- anything greater than 100

Possibly followed by a decimal and two digits. (Thanks to Mike Elofson for pointing out the decimals)

Comment: Worth mentioning, dollar amounts can have $XX.XX, should add the cents values in there.

Answer (score 1):

Well - going all in... This matches (and removes) the $ and takes any numbers over 75.0

```
\b(?<=\$)(7[5-9]|[8-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})\.?\d*$
```

(note that positive lookbehind is not supported in all languages)

But, again a little overkill - its a lot easier to strip the $, convert to double and check if the result is >= 75.0

Comment: Nice, although I believe it would erroneously accept $074, if anyone does that sort of thing.